# How set a cookie from PHP and get it without refresh

Tags: cookies

I know that when use `setcookie()` function it create headers, and after refresh it will be available in `$_COOKIES`, but i need a mechanism to set cookie in this page without redirect, but to be in the browser cookie. If make something like this

```
setcookie('my_cookie','tmp_val');
$_COOKIE['my_cookie'] = 'tmp_val;
```

It is good for case when you set at once, but when you set cookie on each refresh in PHP is good but in browser cookie remains old. I try something like this

```
add_action('parse_request', function($tmp){
            setcookie('my_cookie','tmp_val');
            wp_safe_redirect(get_permalink());
            exit();
        });
```

but I have problems. Please help me in order to find a good solution.

Comment: Why do you need to read it from the cookie if it's within the same request you set in? The whole point of cookies is to persist data between separate requests.

Comment: Because a want a session behavior from cookie,in order to retrieve after refresh, I can use session but the problem is that session after browser close is unset, I think i will use usermeta for this.

Comment: your question is confusing- you say you want it without refresh, then you say you want it after refresh. I have no clue what you're trying to accomplish honestly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the 'init' hook similar to the following:

```
add_action( 'init', 'your_function');
function your_function() {
    setcookie('my_cookie','tmp_val');
    wp_redirect( get_permalink() ); 
        exit; 
    } 
}
```

You should add a conditional 'if' statement in there to prevent it redirecting on every page though!

eg.

```
   add_action( 'init', 'your_function');
    function your_function() {
        setcookie('my_cookie','tmp_val');
        if ($my_cookie == "???") { 
            wp_redirect( 'go here' ); 
            exit; 
            } else {
            wp_redirect( 'go somewhere else' ); 
            exit;
        } 
    }
```

Also consider the 'template_redirect' hook.